# SQL Server doesn't find my function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I use SQL Server 2008 with Borland Delphi in order to develop my applications. Since recently I'm getting a very weird error. I have created several scalar functions that I use in my application, but I'm having a problem with a customer, in his company my software returns the following error when I call my scalar functions:

> Cannot find either column “dbo” or the user-defined function or aggregate “dbo.FunctionName”, or the name is ambiguous."

I've already searched a lot, even here, so keep in mind that:

1. The function exists;
2. I'm quering the correct database;
3. There's no typos;
4. Owner schema is `dbo`;
5. This problem occurs with ALL MY FUNCTIONS;

   And the weirdest...
6. It only happens when I call them from my application, if i run the EXACTLY SAME code at the Query Analyzer using the same user, it will run just fine.

I have this same functions in several other customers, and they don't have any problem. Could it be a SQL Server problem?

Ps: Sorry for my poor English, first question here.

Comment: Do you have more than one database being access in the same server? Or have you tried removing the prefix dbo?

Comment: I have only one database at this server. And when i try call the function without the "dbo" prefix i get this error: 'The "function name" is not a recognized built-in function name'.

Comment: Have a quick check and make sure they aren't using a case sensitive collation. I had a similar issue with parameter names, despite all MS's denials that it could happen.

Comment: I've verified that. However the collation is case insensitive (SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI). The same i use to all my databases.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - Where do MS deny this can happen? [`Parameters for stored procedures or functions, user-defined data types, and variables are assigned the default collation of the database:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214328(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: very strange. did you try with calling other functions? everything else is fine?
how about your connection? what do you use to connect to db from delphi? possibly it changes param.values (I've seen that happen with ODBC), ie "messes up" so sql server cannot recognize function signature

Comment: @MartinSmith. They do that here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx

Comment: Could you post the query (or the relevant fragment thereof) where this error happens? What is your customer's database's compatibility level?

Comment: Guys, thank you very much for the help. @Mark was right, as i said before i use Borland Delphi as my IDE, i also use Devart SDAC as data access component. After his comment i updated this comment and the problem was solved. Looks like it wasn't SQL Server problem after all. I just have one doubt, how do i set Mark comment as right answear?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how QueryAnalyzer calls your functions, but I know this error.
Usually, when you have user-defined functions, you need to prefix the function with the schema name.

So if your function is in schema "dbo", and the name is "fnPadLeft", you need to call the function in code like this:

```
SELECT 
   id
   ,some_field
   ,dbo.fnPadLeft(some_other_field) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```

If you call it like this:

```
SELECT 
   id
   ,some_field
   ,fnPadLeft(some_other_field)  -- lacks dbo.
FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME
```

Then you'll get "no such function".
This only happens to scalar functions btw. (you specifically mentioned this), table-valued functions (and all other non-function things) are not affected by this "feature".

It might also be that you have the same functionname in two schemas (also take a look at the functions in the master database). Maybe your "other functions" are table valued functions.

Comment: thanks for the answer. As i said before in the previous comments, the problem it was my data access components. Nevertheless i appreciate your help very much.